# Pulling N or less latest records using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `Date` (`timestamp` type) column in table called `content`.
How should I write a query to get the latest N records (or less, in case count < N) ??
Using MySQL.

Comment: ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT n ?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `date` DESC limit N;
```

MySQL has a nice keyword `LIMIT` which allows you to get a maximum of the number of records that you want.
The integer following `LIMIT` represents this number. `` ORDER BY `date` ``   -- is making it so that the records will be ordered with the "newest" date values first... thus getting the top N using `LIMIT` is what you want.

Hope it helps.

Cheers